# AccessDeniedException in log before rewriting

Tags: symfony, symfony4

In 4.1 when a user want to access in page with security (@Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')" for example), the user will be redirect in the login page. It's working. I have no error 500.

But in my log /var/log/prod.log i have some error :

```
[2018-06-06 09:30:47] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException: "Access Denied." at /var/www/website/vendor/symfony/security/Http/Firewall/AccessListener.php line 68 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AccessDeniedException(code: 403): Access Denied. at /var/www/website/vendor/symfony/security/Http/Firewall/AccessListener.php:68)"} []
[2018-06-06 09:30:47] security.DEBUG: Access denied, the user is not fully authenticated; redirecting to authentication entry point. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AccessDeniedException(code: 403): Access Denied. at /var/www/website/vendor/symfony/security/Http/Firewall/AccessListener.php:68)"} []
[2018-06-06 09:30:47] security.DEBUG: Calling Authentication entry point. [] []
```

I don't understand why I have critical error.

Comment: no he doesn't have an error, for my exemple we can see in log critical error

Comment: Do you get the same log in development mode?

Comment: yes when I try to get the same issue on symfony/demo it's doesn't work :( but I have same security.yaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symfony Framework defines a `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener` that subscribes to `KernelEvents::EXCEPTION` with very high priority of **2048** for method `logKernelException` (see https://github.com/symfony/http-kernel/blob/master/EventListener/ExceptionListener.php#L93) :

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => array(
            array('logKernelException', 2048),
            array('onKernelException', -128),
        ),
    );
}
```

So thrown `AccessDeniedException` is firstly handled by this `logKernelException` method that logs it with **CRITICAL** level (see https://github.com/symfony/http-kernel/blob/master/EventListener/ExceptionListener.php#L109) :

```
protected function logException(\Exception $exception, $message)
{
    if (null !== $this->logger) {
        if (!$exception instanceof HttpExceptionInterface || $exception->getStatusCode() >= 500) {
            $this->logger->critical($message, array('exception' => $exception));
        } else {
            $this->logger->error($message, array('exception' => $exception));
        }
    }
}
```

At this step, `AccessDeniedException` has been logged on the **request** channel. It's totally relevant from the request scope : original request has failed because no authentication had been performed...

Then, `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ExceptionListener`, listening `KernelEvents::EXCEPTION` but handling only authentication related ones (see https://github.com/symfony/security/blob/master/Http/Firewall/ExceptionListener.php#L87) goes on duties in order to redirect to authentication start point...

Comment: Thx for this explains, I understand this problem now. 

But for me, an access denied is not a critical error, I post an issue in GitHub and waiting for response.

Comment: This issue resolved the problem juste wait for 4.1.1 https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/4435144a24bea3d8b064a7825121132abcc7c005